# JavaScript equivalent of php DOMDocument Object

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, domdocument

I wrote a code in PHP for parsing data that I received by an API request from "wikipedia.org".
I used DOMDocument class to parse the data and it worked perfectly fine. Now I want to do the same job in JavaScript. The API request returns (after a little cleaning up) a string like this:

```
$htmlString = "<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>"
```

**Note that this is just an example. Any request might have different number of lists, but it is always a series of unordered lists.**
I needed to get the text inside the `<li>` tags and the following PHP code worked perfectly fine.

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlString);
$lis = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('li');
$items =[];
for ($i = 0; $i < $lis->length; $i++) $items[] = $lis[$i]->nodeValue;
```

And I get the array [Item 1,...,Item 5] inside `$items` variable as I wanted.
Now I want to do the same job in JavaScript. That is I have a string

```
htmlString = "<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>"
```

in JavaScript and I want to get the text inside each of the `<li>` tags. I searched the web for an equivalent class to PHP DOMDocument in JavaScript, and surprisingly I found nothing.
Any ideas how to do this in (preferably Vanilla) JavaScript similar to the PHP code?
If not, any idea how to do this anyway in JavaScript (even maybe with regular expressions)?

Comment: Are you running the Javascript in a browser, or on a server (under Node, etc)?

Comment: jQuery does this rather well. It uses css selectors to query for items in the dom. A lot of criticism of it out there despite it's rather wide use so do some research before adopting.

Comment: @ iainn I am running in a browser. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @danielson317 That is true. The problem is, I do not want to select the li's from my own page's DOM. It is the li's in the html string that I need to grab.

Comment: @MathCoder you can create a jquery object from an html string: `$(string).find('li')`

Comment: PD of [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or Prototype](//stackoverflow.com/q/494143) / [Create a DOM document from string, without JQuery](//stackoverflow.com/q/9598791)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DOMParser()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Your ported code, which is very much the same as your PHP:

```js
let parser = new DOMParser()
let doc = parser.parseFromString(`<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>`, "text/html")


let lis = doc.getElementsByTagName('li')
let items = []
for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) items.push(lis[i].textContent)

console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working strictly with strings, you want to use Regular Expressions.

**FYI**
*I'm using ES20xx syntax. If you can't support this, you'll need to convert to the syntax you're users can access.*

Here I have an expressions that captures whatever is in between opening `<ul>` or `<li>` and the closing tags. Then I use the line breaks to split the string into an array. We need to filter out empty elements from the resulting array and finally return the desired items in a final array.

```js
var htmlString = `<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>`;

var lis = htmlString.replace(/<ul>|<li>(.*)<\/li>|<\/ul>/g, '$1').split('\n');

var items = lis
    .filter(item => {
        if (item && item !== null && item !== '') {
            return item;
        }
    })
    .map(item => {
        var element = item.replace(/\s{2,}/g, '');

        return element;
    });

console.log('items array.', items);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am hopefully looking for an answer which is more or less similar to my php code. Something more systematic that could be used in other situations. But your answer works perfectly fine here. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with an example that will allow me to better address the concern you have. I can only work with what you've told us.